# Access EJB from Web module

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I'm trying to get an instance of EJB from JSF web module in Enterprise Application. So I did it like this.

First I have an Interface

```
import javax.ejb.Remote;

@Remote
public interface ICrawlerBean {
    public void startCrawler();
}
```

Then I have EJB that implements this interface:

```
@Stateless( name="CrawlerB")
@LocalBean
public class CrawlerBean implements ICrawlerBean{

    @Override
    public void startCrawler() {
        CrawlerController cc = new CrawlerController();
        try {
            cc.run();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(CrawlerBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Both of these are on EJB side. Next I have Managed Bean of web module

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class HomeContoller extends HttpServlet{

    private String title = "Home";

    @EJB
    private CrawlerB cb; //Error is here; cannot find symbol

    public HomeController() {
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void crawl(){

    }
}
```

I have to say I found all of this in various tutorials and I'm not experienced with Enterprise Applications, so any help would be great. 
So, I can't get to my EJB as you can see in this last class. It's like it doesn't exist. I guess I did something wrong, but I can't seem to find a solution

Comment: `Cannot find symbol` is a compiler error message. It can't compile because there is no `CrawlerB` class in the classpath. Use `@EJB private ICrawlerBean cb;`

Comment: I have changed `@Stateless( name="CrawlerB")` to `@Stateless( name="CrawlerBean")` and used `@EJB private ICrawlerBean cb;`, and I still get the same error

Comment: Show your stacktrace.

Comment: You must also be sure your environment is correctly set up. The Web application must be able to see the EJB app (the classes you use must be available at build time, the interfaces you export must be available at web deploy and runtime). If you are using an IDE the EJB project usually should be a dependency of the Web project.

Comment: I have Enterprise App. So I have EJB module and Web module. Your comment solved my problem. I have added EJB as a library to Web module and it worked. Thanks.
Could you just write it as an answer so I can mark it as accepted

Comment: Show your stacktrace. If it compiles and doesn't run, your stacktrace should say why.